# PCIe slot speeds

Tags: pci-express

I'm really rather confused by it all, so I've come up with a question or two:

1. If I buy a motherboard with a PCIe x16 and PCIe x4 slot and put a graphics card in each, will they both run at x8 speeds due to the x16 being split in half, or will they run at x16 and x4?
2. If I buy two ATI 6850s (let's simplify it to "top-midrange graphics cards"), will there be a noticeable performance drop from running one of them at x4 speeds. They'll be in CrossfireX (linked).

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this question.

Comment: I think Superuser is the best place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The one in the x4 slot won't run at x8; it needs a x8 or x16 slot to do that. They will run at x16 and x4.
2. Look on a benchmarking site.

Comment: Thanks very much Brian. This was my though too, but I read about bus sharing and thought that might have an impact.

Comment: There is no bus sharing in PCIe - it's all point-to-point.

Answer (score 1):

The one in the x4 slot can't run at x8 speeds.  The x4 slot is limited to x4.  The slots don't split their speed amongst each other like that.